# Sagemath console issue

Tags: sage

I recently installed the latest version(9.2) of SageMath on my Laptop. When I proceed to open the SageMath console, instead of displaying "sage:" it is stuck as shown below:

[image]

I'm not sure what the issue is exactly; I've also waited around 10 mins each time

Comment: I guess it's Windows? What version (not that it would help me since I don't have a Windows machine, but it might help others)? I would suggest also asking at ask.sagemath.org.

Answer (score 0):

Some antivirus may have blocked or destroyed parts of Sage.

On Windows, Sage uses Cygwin, which antivirus software
tend to mis-classify as virus-like.

Suggestion:

- uninstall SageMath
- download the SageMath installer
- define the SageMath installer as harmless for any antivirus
- run the SageMath installer
- define the installed SageMath and its underlying Cygwin as harmless for any antivirus

Each antivirus lets users define a list of programs
it should not interfere with. See for instance:

- [Excluding certain files or websites from scanning in Avast Antivirus](https://support.avast.com/en-ww/article/Antivirus-scan-exclusions)